# angular2 http.post The original address and destination address are together

Tags: http, angular, post

Angular2 `http.post(http://127.0.0.1:555)`

Chrome developer network show 
`post "http://127.0.0.1:4444/127.0.0.1:5555"` is not found

`"http://127.0.0.1:5555"` is node server

`"http://127.0.0.1:4444"` is angular2 server

Why the two stack together?

post component
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
    import {PostDetailService} from './post-detail.service';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-detail',
  templateUrl: './post-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-detail.component.scss']
})                                                                    
export class PostDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  postDetail= {
    title: '',
    userName: '',
    postWriteTime: 0,
    readTimes: 0,
    commentTimes: 0
  };
  opts = {
  url: 'http:127.0.0.1:5555/postDetail',
  body: '',
};                                                            
  constructor(private router: Router, private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute, private postDetailService: PostDetailService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activateRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
      this.opts.body = params['postId'];
      console.log(params, 'params');
    });
   this.getPostDetailById();
  }
  getPostDetailById() {
    this.postDetailService.getPostDetail(this.opts).subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res, 'res');
        },
        err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log("complete"));
  }

}
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
@Injectable()
export class PostDetailService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {}
    getPostDetail(opts): Observable<any> {
        console.log(opts, 'opts');
        return this.http.post(opts.url, opts.body).
          map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server error'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code that causes this output. It's probably an error in how you create the URL.

Comment: Please post the code that allows to reproduce and please edit your question and add it there because code in comments is usually unreadable.

Comment: The code is below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url should be

```
url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5555/postDetail',
```

instead of

```
url: 'http:127.0.0.1:5555/postDetail',
```